# Bash scrip that will find specific lines associated with the current date and time

Tags: bash, shell, awk

```
c=$(awk -v d1="$(date --date="-30 min" "+%b %_d %H:%M")" -v d2="$(date 
"+%b %_d %H:%M")" '$0 > d1 && $0 < d2 || $0 ~ d2' /var/place/message| 
grep -ci "Important message") 

if [ $c-gt 0 ] 
then
 echo "Found message"
else
 echo "fail"
fi
```

I want my script to be able to find an important message in a log that are 
btwn the current time and -30 min.

The log looks like this

March 14 03:03:41 blah blah blah "Important message"

March 14 03:03:42 blah blah blah

March 14 03:03:43 blah blah blah

...

March 14 03:31:41 blah blah blah "Important message"

So if the current time was 4:00:00 it would find the last line.
This doesn't work at all..I get two errors. the first being that grep can't find the message and the second one is '-gt unary operator expected'. Any guidance would be amazing. First time scripting in bash!!
Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

your date format doesn't match your log.

```
$ awk -v d1="$(date -d "-30 min" "+%B %d %H:%M")"    \
      -v d2="$(date "+%B %d %H:%M")" '
       $0>d1 && $0<d2 && /Important message/ {c++}
       END {print c; exit !c}' file
```

just check the return status of this script.  if you don't need the count, you can get rid of some noise (add `;exit` after `c++`, and remove `print c`.

Alternatively, you can add the "found" or "fail" messages in the same script as well...

**NB.** This will not work around midnight on month changes, For example `April xx < March xx` based on lexical order.

Comment: what does the {c++} END do?

Comment: `c++` is increment `c`(ounter).  `END` is the end block, will run once just before exit.

Comment: Thank you. When i run the script nothing happens.

Comment: doesn't even print the count?  Not even 0?

Comment: No it doesn't:(

Comment: This is what i have ->   c= $(awk -v d1="$(date -d "-30 min"  "+%B %d %H:%M")" -v d2="$(date "+%B %d %H:%M")" '$0>d1 && $0<d2 && 'ERROR MESSAGE' {c++} END {print c; exit !c} mail.log

Comment: that's not what my script says.  Get rid of `c=$(..)`; run the contents of  the parenthesis.  You have to put the string you're searching between slashes as in my example.  You can `echo $?` to get the status.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any space after the backslash on the first line.  The post doesn't have, but copy/paste might introduce one.

Comment: $ awk -v d1="$(date -d "-30 min" "+%B %d %H:%M")"    
      -v d2="$(date "+%B %d %H:%M")" '
       $0>d1 && $0<d2 && /message/ {c++}
       END {print c; exit !c}' mail.log

Comment: that is what i have